# React Native FlatList can't scroll

Tags: css, react-native, styles, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

**I can't scroll my child component inside the flatlist**,hope someone chould help me! if you need more detail,please let me know.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <FlatList                                                               
                  data={DATA}  
                  keyExtractor={(item)=>item.key}
                  renderItem={({item})=>(

                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>  
                        <View>
                            <Text>item1</Text>        
                        </View> 

                        <View>
                            <Text>item2</Text>        
                        </View> 

                        <View>
                            <Text>item3</Text>        
                        </View> 
                                  .
                                  . 
                                  .
                    </View>  
    </FlatList>  
<View/>
```

Comment: Do you have a Scroll Vew inside this component? Also if you want a component to be horizontal scroll you can use the horizontal props: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal

Comment: This code seems to scroll, besides having a performance issue as it's rendering an array of items for it item: https://snack.expo.dev/7xjWuQZCr

Comment: Your last view is wrong `<View/>` should be `</View>`

Comment: sorry maybe i'dont express clearly. I want to do something like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlbKX.png).